# In Spring Boot 2 how can I accept LocalDates as RequestParams

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC1.  I can see this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/2fa0539e7f7bf93505f67303955cc7da6f9f5846 and the class WebConversionService on my classpath.  I can provide a bean of it with my chosen date format.  However this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/test"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
fun test2(@RequestParam param: LocalDate): LocalDate {
    return param
}
```

Still doesn't work when I call it with "2018-01-01".  I'm aware I can use @DateTimeFormat but I'm trying to avoid that and set the format globally (or ideally not set it at all and have it just work, like it does for parsing JSON bodies)

Comment: my first question is, what version of spring boot are you using, it only supports 2.0.0 RC1 and above

Comment: Yes I'm using 2.0.0 RC1

Comment: after reading about this feature it seems it is only available for the new "Spring Webflux" api and not for the regular REST Web.

Answer (score 1):

For this new feature to work, you need to set the `spring.mvc.date-format` property in your `application.properties`.

Note that there seems to be a problem with using the common ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd`: when I tried with that, I ran into the following exception:

`Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-04-20'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-04-20]`

Through debugging, I found that the root cause is this exception:

`Text '2018-04-20' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=20, YearOfEra=2018, MonthOfYear=4},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

And I also found that the `DateTimeFormatter` that gets used for parsing is represented like that by `toString()`:

`Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)`

I *presume* that the reason why a `LocalDate` could not be obtained is that the `TemporalAccessor` that gets constructed lacks a value for the `Era` field, but has a filled `YearOfEra` field.

So I tried with `uuuu-MM-dd` instead (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the distinction between `y` and `u`), which works perfectly:

`spring.mvc.date-format=uuuu-MM-dd`

**UPDATE**

Opened a new [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13970) on GitHub.